# Could we get "Too localized" as proposal close reason in Area51?

Tags: feature-request

[Insurance in Texas](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54938/insurance-in-texas) has just received its fifth vote with 3 "not a viable proposal" and 2 "Poorly defined".

> Proposed Q&A site for licensed insurance agents and representatives in Texas.

That's a fairly good definition, I'd say. Estimating risks, understanding regulations, costs comparisons - these would make reasonable questions.

I believe "Insurance" in general would be a viable proposal - for agents, inspectors, customers, people calculating risks and insurance values etc. The subject is broad enough and would make for a viable proposal.

A site for Insurance agents in Texas - and then what, another A51 site for Insurance brokers in Nebraska? The actual reason for this closure is too narrow scope. I think it should either be a separate reason, or added as the explanation of "Not a viable proposal".

Comment: *"The actual reason for this closure is too narrow scope"*... which would make the site as a whole not viable. Does that really need a "too localized"?

Comment: I'm not registered on Area51; but I think you can create a discussion and mention this?

Comment: I guess my idea for an Andrew Barber Questions site won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Area51 has its flaws, and I'm hoping that the current work being done by Stack Exchange developers will radically rework it.

But one thing it does do reasonably well, is give chance for sites to build support, and to do a test launch, to enable the concept to be market-tested. There are very very few people, if any, who can know in advance whether a site will be successful or not.

The best way to find out, is to try to launch it, and see what happens.

As the saying goes: the secret of success is - fail cheap, fail early, fail often. The Area51 process partly enables that.  **The only real test of a site's viability is to launch it, and see how it goes.**

If "Insurance in Texas" is too narrow a scope, then the site won't launch at all, or will fail in private beta, or in public beta. **So the existing process already has a mechanism to kill off sites that are too narrow**, and that's done by the best-possible testing mechanism - real market testing. Not the opinion of anyone who considers themselves an expert, but by real market testing of real potential users.

Just adding a mechanism whereby a few highly-repped Area51 participants could kill off a proposal, solely because in their opinion it's too localised, adds nothing of value, and would actually detract from the process. Because **having a high rep on Area51 doesn't mean a user knows anything at all about the near-market for a new proposal on subject X**, where X could be Insurance in Texas, or Chinchilla-racing (I thought I'd just made that up, but apparently it's actually a thing), or whatever.

So please can we continue without a “Too localized” close-reason in Area51. I'd go further, and remove "not viable" as a reason.  I think "illegal", "unconstructive", or "damaging to the Stack Exchange" brand are good reasons for Area51 users to be able to close a proposal; but opining that there is an insufficient market is not a good reason, and should not be a close mechanism.